# Test for the "inf" value in OpenSCAD

Tags: openscad, type-testing

I am relatively new to `OpenSCAD`, but I have plenty of experience in software development. I have written the following `function`:

`function GetSlope(angle)=sin(angle)/cos(angle);`

When the angle is 90° or 270° the `function` will, of course, return `inf` due to `cos` evaluating to 0, and therefore trying to divide by 0. This is obviously to be expected, but I need to be able to detect this when using the `function`. `OpenSCAD` contains several type-testing functions, but I could not find an `is_inf` function or a constant named `inf` to do my own test. Is there a way to test for `inf`, or do I need to manually test the value from outside the `function`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `1/0` as the `inf` constant you are looking for, it's not very clean but it works. You could also check if `cos(angle) == 0` although I don't think that's what you want.

(*also you may already know it but `sin(angle) / cos(angle) = tan(angle)`*)

##### UPDATE :

according to [the documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/General#Numbers) :

> The constants `inf` and `nan` are not supported as numeric constants by OpenSCAD, even though you can compute numbers that are printed this way by 'echo'. You can define variables with these values by using:  `inf = 1e200 * 1e200; nan = 0 / 0; echo(inf,nan);`